# Domain Aggregate DI in method calls

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate entitled `Payment` and I expose a method called `Capture`. From the API controller I am invoking the aggregate like so:

```
var payment = _mapper.Map<Payment>(request); // auto mapper
var response = await payment.Capture(_paymentCaptureDecorator); // decorator injected into controller
```

Question I have I am using a decorator pattern to help me with this flow of calls as it:

- One, attempts to retreive a payment from the database, if so short circuits and returns it
- Second, makes the call to the bank (this is not done in the domain but the interface is defined but implemented in another class library)
- Thirdly and lastly it saves the payment as an entity

In all 3 decorators they call into the aggregate as the sole job of the decorator is to perform some mapping and invoke the aggregate. For example:

```
public class AcquirerDecorator : IPaymentCaptureDecorator
{
    private readonly IPaymentCaptureDecorator _decorator;
    private readonly IAcquirerAdapter _acquirerAdapter;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AcquirerDecorator(
        IPaymentCaptureDecorator decorator,
        IAcquirerAdapter acquirerAdapter,
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _decorator = decorator;
        _acquirerAdapter = acquirerAdapter;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    
    public async Task<PaymentResponse> Execute(Payment payment)
    {
        var acquirerRequest = _mapper.Map<AcquirerRequestDto>(payment);
        await payment.AcquireFunds(_acquirerAdapter, acquirerRequest);
        return await _decorator.Execute(payment);
    }
}
```

The aggregate then does this:

```
public async Task AcquireFunds(IAcquirerAdapter acquirerAdapter, AcquirerRequestDto acquirerRequest)
{
    AcquirerResponse = await acquirerAdapter.CaptureFunds(acquirerRequest); // sets state on aggregate
}

// Called by another decorator
public async Task Save(ISavePaymentCommand savePaymentCommand, PaymentTransactionEntity entity)
{
    Card.Sanitise(); // modify state of the aggregate removing sensitive card info
    if (AcquirerResponse.IsSuccessful)
    {
        await savePaymentCommand.Execute(entity);
    }
}
```

This allows me to use constructor injection in the decorator and then pass the dependencies into the aggregate.

Arguably, the aggregate can do all of this but it would also mean I would need to use property injection or have a fairly big contructor. It would also mean that it would be aware of mapping data types which I don't think the aggregate should do.

Is this a perfectly OK thing to do?

Comment: "Is this a perfectly OK thing to do?" I'd say it's not. The domain model should ideally be free of out of process dependencies, hence shouldn't be talking to gateways, DBs, etc. not even under the disguise of an interface. The domain model should process pure state transitions and services at the system boundaries are responsible for the external side-effects.

Checking the code above, I feel it's extremely obfuscated with infrastructure & technical stuff and business processes are lost.

Comment: What's the business use case you're trying to model, process a payment due or a bill? That's most likely a long running process as it involves external services and you need strong reliability in case of failures (e.g. card charged but ack fails).

Comment: Processing a payment is what I am modeling. I guess the aggregate should be aware of the outcome and not orchestrating it? If so the aggregate isn't doing a lot apart from being told what has happened and perhaps making decisions if something can happen. I thought the aggregate should be doing and not simply being asked?

Comment: An aggregate is responsible for the consistency of the data within it's own boundary. If an AR speaks to a DB or performs side-effects through collaborators then it's acting upon data it has no control over. Generally speaking you might have an AR that transitions it's state & fires an event which is recorded in the same TX as the state transition. The event will then be processed by a messaging infrastructure handler, etc.

Comment: For instance, you might have a `Payment` that is `awaiting processing`, then when card info is provided you'd try to process it `payment.process()` which perhaps fires a `PaymentProcessingStarted` even then handled by a processor which does the side-effects and waits for confirmation upon which it calls `payment.confirm()` to mark the payment as completed or perhaps `payment.reject` if it didin't go through. I dont know much about payment processing so the terms I used may not make sense, but the idea is to extract side-effects at the system boundary and use ARs for consistency.

Comment: ARs will "do" rather than simply "record" when they are the book of record. If the book of record is external, an AR cant' possibly have authority on that. Reliable messaging infrastructure is also needed to make distributed systems consistent which will be hard if you just attempt to process everything synchronously.

Comment: The doing is why I thought injecting the dependencies was a good idea as it's coordinating these actions and updating its own state. I guess I can do this in application services and have methods like payment confirmed or payment rejected like you have.